# Using gamepad hardware controllers with games that don't explicitly support them?

Tags: game-controllers

War Robots, which is a very popular game, AFAIK has no support for gamepads. (Thus limiting interaction to the touch screen).

Yet in this [forum thread](http://war-robots-forum.freeforums.net/thread/1980/android-gamepad-support?page=1&scrollTo=184577) one person reports *some* success with a gamepad. (Logitec F310)

Does this mean that War Robots *must* have support programmed in? Or not? It's been suggested a rooted device is necessary, but I don't see that being likely, since the gamepad is surely merely acting as a HID alternative to touching the screen?

The forum thread mentioned that the mapping of keys with the Logitec F310 is not ideal. Why is this not configurable? (Might it be configurable on others? Or is it hard-programmed somewhere?)

**Why I ask**: I want to buy a gamepad to play War Robots but at the moment I'd be buying blind without any idea if, or how well, it would work.

Comment: While the game wiki states that it doesn't support controllers directly on solution could be to use an android emulator and play your game from there, MEmu emulator has support for mouse and keyboard and you could play in your big screen from your sofa.